# sencha horizontal scroll with a list

Tags: list, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.3

I am trying follow the list-horizontal example given by Sencha.
I am getting a message saying
 ( The base layout for a DataView must always be a Fit Layout ) 
In the example it is not a fit layout. Could someone please tell me what I am missing here.
Thanks
Jim

```
  Ext.define( 'Styles.view.Beginning', { 
    extend: 'Ext.List',
    xtype: 'beginninglist',

    config: {
     title:'Beginning',
     iconCls: 'star',


 layout:{
     type:'vbox',
     pack: 'center'
 },
   items:[

    {

      //give it an xtype of list for the list component
                xtype: 'dataview',
                height: 250,


                scrollable: 'horizontal',
                directionLock: true,
                inline: {
                    wrap: false
                },


                //set the itemtpl to show the fields for the store
                itemTpl: '{name} {image}',


                //bind the store to this list
                 store: 'Beginning'

    }

     ]

   }
  });
```

Comment: Why are you extending the view with `Ext.List`. Since you are using dataview you should extend `Ext.dataview.DataView` and you will see the  error will not come.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to learn Sencha layouting. You can refere [here](http://html5wood.com/sencha-touch-2-layout-tutorials-demos-and-examples/). You were creating a `List` and then trying to put `Dataview` inside that. So if you need Dataview, directly extend Dataview like below:

```
Ext.define('Styles.view.Beginning', {
        extend: 'Ext.dataview.DataView',
        xtype: 'beginninglist',
        config: {
            inline: {
                wrap: false
            },
            scrollable: {
                direction: 'horizontal'
            },

            //set the itemtpl to show the fields for the store
            itemTpl: '{name} {image}',

            //bind the store to this list
            store: 'Beginning'
        }
    });
```